# Create a div with aspect ratio 1:1 knowing only its height in percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if you can help me with this.
I have a div (in white) where I need to put two circular buttons (in green) on the borders. Everything should be done with CSS.
It should look like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Fai.png)

Now, the thing is that I don't know the size of the white div, and I won't know it at the time of creation, because it will get added to the DOM afterwards. All I know is that the white div has a percentage width and height relative to its future parent. So, at the time of creation, since it's not yet added, any calls to width(), height() or its css values won't work.
I've seen all those snippets that tell you how to make a div with a fixed aspect ratio. I need this now, I need the button to be 1:1, but all I know about the dimensions, is that it has to be 100% of the height of the white div (and therefore, its width should be equal as its height). All the examples I've seen assume that you know the width and to make the height keep the ratio. In my case, what I know is the height (100%) and I want the width to adapt.
I have no idea how to achieve this.

This is my snippet:

```css
body{
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 7%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
.arrow {
  background: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.arrow:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-right: 100%;
}
.arrow:last-child {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7bxecL9m/

If you know how can I do this without entering any fixed value (jQuery use is of course valid), I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many variables here:

- Since container's `height` is `%` and circle `radius` is `px` units, one is static and the other one will resize.
- The only way to preserve 1:1 with just html/css, considering the container's `height` `%` will resize circle's `height` as well, would be to isolate circle's `div` `width` & `height` to something static like `px` units.
- Now, since you said no fixed dimensions, the only thing I can think of is to comment `.arrow`'s `100%` `height`, to prevent resizing other than 1:1, and nesting a `div` inside `.arrow` to restrain 1:1 with static units (ideally impacting `.arrow` directly would be less code but if you don't want/can't set them on that element, maybe you consider this).

If you want the circle to remain circular as the content expands, you need to dynamically adjust the height to match the width. You could use Javascript to achieve this, but your `border-radius` is tied to `container`'s in `px` static units, since container will always be bigger something like `border-radius: 50%` wouldn't work for both, 50% `radius` of circle would never match 50% of `container`'s (that is, if you care about radius alignment).

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 37%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow {
  background: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bLimit {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-right: 100%;
}
.arrow:last-child {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="bLimit">button overflow</div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="bLimit">button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot about the fixed radius, I just put it there for testing, but it doesn't have to be fixed. It can be a percentage as well. Now the container will change size but not ratio, it will always be a fixed percentage height of its parent, and a fixed percentage width. And its parent, once added, will always resize evenly

Comment: Sorry, I've pressed Enter too quickly.
I forgot about the fixed radius, I just put it there for testing, but it doesn't have to be fixed. It can be a percentage as well. 
One thing I didn't mention (I forgot) is that the container will change size but not ratio, it will always be a fixed percentage height of its parent, and a fixed percentage width. And its parent, once the container gets added, will also resize evenly, so the radius of .container will stay the same (in percentage) and therefore the .arrow can be the same as well.
I'm gonna try your approach and see how it goes, thanks!

Comment: It worked, but of course, any resizing will leave the circle intact while the rest changes, and that's not the idea. I guess I'll have to add some javascript for detecting changes, maybe I can bind an event to check when it's getting inserted into the dom, and once that happens, I can ask for its parent's width and height.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pablo if you wish to preserve radius alignment, percentage wouldn't work anyways either, because it's not proportional to it's child. Imagine without fixed dimensions on buttons, you load different sizes you would have to calculate depending on each size it's border-radius percentage to match it's container's different radius percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing a fixed width in percent for your arrow :

```
.arrow {
  background: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: I think doing that would not maintain the aspect ratio, I need the button to be a perfect circle. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Then put a fixed size in pixels instead

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 7%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
.container:after,.container:before{
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  padding: 4%;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  position:absolute;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.container:before {
  left: 0;
}
.container:after{
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

You can achieve using `before` and `after` CSS pseudo selectors. You check this [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7bxecL9m/3/).

Comment: The circles will maintain aspect ratio, but won't respond correctly to changes in the size of the container --- > https://jsfiddle.net/a649h726/

Comment: Precisely what ovokuro said, if you resize that window, you'll see that the circles, while still a perfect circle, don't mantain the 100% height relative to the white div. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There is a posibility to get this result using a image (that won't show) of the required ratio.

In this case, the ratio is 1:1 so we will use an image of 50px (but it can be any size)

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.container:nth-child(2) {
  height: 40px;
}
.container:nth-child(3) {
  height: 60px;
}
.arrow {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.arrow:last-child {
  right: 0px;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
</div>
```